# Apollo Client - fetchMore component update problem

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

In my *NextJS* application interfaced with a *MongoDB* API back-end - managed via *GraphQL*, I'm trying to implement the *Apollo* `fetchMore` feature, in order to update a component responsible to load more items from a data collection.

On page rendering, the component itself shows a "gallery" of 10 elements as its native functionality, populated via a GraphQL starting query. Then, I included a "load more" button to trigger the `fetchMore` function. The UX expects that if the user clicks the proper button, more 10 elements will going to be loaded in addition of the previous 10 - basically a classical async-infinite loading example.

By inspecting the app, I notice that both the queries are being returned successfully - the initialization one and the "load more 10 items" too managed by `fetchMore` - but the latter, after its execution, triggers the component's update that it's being re-initialized with the starter query instead of the `fetchMore` one.

To clarify it: on "load more" click, instead to see the next 10 gallery elements loaded - so to finally display a total of 20 - the component refreshes and displays the starter 10 elements, like its starting initialization - totally ignoring the `fetchMore` action, even if this one is being called, executed and received back with a populated 200 response.

Because this is my very first time in using it, I don't know if I'm missing something in my implementation, or I need to fix something. Anyway, here it goes:

Due to various reasons, I'm running the query in a parent component, then I pass the data as props to a child one:

**Parent**

```
// Initialization, etc.
[...]

const {loading: loadingIndex, error: errorIndex, data: dataIndex, fetchMore: fetchMoreIndex} = useQuery(ARTICLE_QUERY.articles.indexArticles, {
    // Last 30 days
    variables: {
      live: live,
      limit: 10
    }
  });

  // Exception check
  if (errorIndex) {
    return <ErrorDb error={errorIndex} />
  }
  // DB fetching check
  if (loadingIndex) {
    return (
      <section className="index-articles">
        <h6>Index - Articles</h6>
        <aside className="articles__loading">
          <h6>Loading</h6>
        </aside>
      </section>
    );
  }

  const articles = dataIndex.queryArticleContents;

  return (
    <IndexArticles labels={props.labels} articles={articles} fetchMore={fetchMoreIndex} />
  );
```

**Child**

````
// Initialization, etc.
[...]

let limit = 10; // My query hypothetically limiter
const IndexArticles = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // This is a getter method responsible to manage the ```fetchMore``` response
    getArticles(props.articles, props.fetchMore);
  });

return (
    <>
     // Component sections
    [...]

     // Load button
    {props.fetchMore &&
          <button className="articles__load" title={props.labels.index.title} tabIndex={40}>{props.labels.index.cta}</button>
        }
    </>
);

function getArticles(articles, fetchMore) {
  // Yes, I'm using jQuery with React. Just ignore it
  $('.articles__load').on('click tap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    $('.articles__loading').removeClass('hidden');

    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        // Cursor is being pointed to the last available element of the current collection
        lastLoaded: articles.length,
        limit: limit += 10
      },
      updateQuery: (prev, {fetchMoreResult, ...rest}) => {
        $('.articles__loading').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');

        if (!fetchMoreResult) {
          return prev;
        }

        return {
          ...fetchMoreResult,
          queryArticleContents: [
            ...prev.queryArticleContents,
            ...fetchMoreResult.queryArticleContents
          ]
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
````

Anyone have experience with it or had experienced this case before?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested on the official community, my configuration was missing about the `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` in the query options, which is responsible to update the component and append the new data.

By changing the code in this way:

**Parent**

```
const {
  loading: loadingIndex, 
  error: errorIndex, 
  data: dataIndex, 
  // Add networkStatus property too in order to use notifyOnNetworkStatusChange properly
  networkStatus: networkStatusIndex
  fetchMore: fetchMoreIndex} = useQuery(ARTICLE_QUERY.articles.indexArticles, {
    // Last 30 days
    variables: {
      live: live,
      limit: 10
    },
    // Important for component refreshing with new data
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true 
  });
```

The problem has been solved.